# C++ Vector Sorts

Tags: c++, vector

I am working with a vector in Codefights for the "almostIncreasingSequence" challenge. Is there a way to track how many "steps" a sort method takes when so I can set a simple counter/flag to check against if the sort passes a predefined threshold?

Comment: Nope not using `std::sort`. You'd have to write your own sort, then you can count whatever you want (comparisions, `std::swap`s, etc). You can find many animations and comparisons online about the time complexity of various sorts (merge sort, bubble sort, quick sort, etc)

Comment: @CoryKramer This is not true in the most strict sense, since you can simply use a custom (stateful) comparator and [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) specialization

Comment: You can provide a comparator that counts the number of comparisons, and throws an exception if some bound is exceeded.   But most algorithms specify upper bounds on the number of comparisons anyway - you'd be better off checking against that before attempting the sort than trying to detect how many comparisons are actually done.

Comment: @Tobias - `std::sort()` is not required to use `std::swap()` - and some real world implementations do not.

Comment: @Peter I stand corrected, I misinterpreted the requirements for the iterator type. So implementing a comperator and the move assignment operator should cover all cases, right? (since `std::swap` uses move assignment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is. You can use a custom comparison function with [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> myVector { 2, 8, 5, 9, 3, 7, 1, 4, 6, 0 };

    int counter = 0;
    std::sort(myVector.begin(), myVector.end(), [&counter](int lhs, int rhs) {
        counter++;
        return lhs < rhs;
    });

    std::cout << "Steps: " << counter << std::endl;
    for(auto e : myVector)
        std::cout << e << ' ';
    std::cout << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```